# Can't delete directory with 777 permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I have created a directory `/var/dir` as root and give permission like:

```
#chown -R kute:kute /var/dir
#ls-l /var/dir
#drwxrwxrwx  2 kute kute  4096 May 30 04:04 /var/dir
```

and then i login as kute and tried to delete the directory. but it shows like

> rm: cannot remove `/var/dir': Permission denied

And I can't give write permission to parent directory to delete the file

Comment: did you tried with `rmdir` ? `rm` is used to delete files and not directory unless its having `-R` flag

Comment: What are the permissions of `/var`? Could be that it belongs to root, so that it makes sense that you are not allowed any of its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is not a directory. Sorry, but that is a symbolic link as you can see when looking at the permissions. Whatever you did, you did *not* create that directory. And the permissions line you posted certainly is *not* complete. The inode the link points to is missing.

Comment: What directory? If the symbolic link is removed, then `/var/dir` does not exist any more. So what directory are you talking about? I mentioned before that you did not post where that link points to (pointed to).

Comment: Sure, that is all fine. But what is the problem now? You said you removed the link. So that is not the problem. You should be able to remove your own directory in your own home folder. So that is not the problem too. So what _is_ the problem? Or do you mean you cannot remove that link you created with root permissions when trying to remove it with permissions of the user `kute`? Then check the permissions of `/var`! User `kute` does not have write permissions in there. He cannot alter the contents of that folder!

Comment: The OP cannot delete the dir /var/dir because probably /var belongs to root.

Comment: problem is : 1) I created /var/dir and give chown -R kute:kute /var/dir 2)I want to give symlink between /var/dir and /home/kute/test. But when i tried it, I got like /var/dir/test, really i want is /var/dir-> /home/kute/test

Comment: You can do that, but again: you cannot write into folder `/var` if you violate the permissions to _that_ folder. It has nothing to do with permissions of that link itself. This is simply how unixoid file systems work. What you could try is this: add user `kute` to the group the folder `/var` belongs to. Then, if `/var` is made group writable, user `kute` can create or delete inodes in that folder. Note that you should relogin after granting group membership to not get confused.

Comment: I have done like 1) As root - # mkdir /var/website , # chown kute:kute /var/website       2) Login as kute and tried 'ln -s /home/kute/test /var/dir. Instead of getting like /var/dir-> /home/kute/test , I am getting /var/dir/test -> /home/kute/test

Comment: @Kute, you are wrong somewhere. Try to include all these details in question body and reformulate it to state actual problem. You will probably see what's wrong yourself.